# Pass DateTimePicker Value to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have two `DateTimePicker` on my form `dtp_VacationStart` and `dtp_VacationEnd` . I'd like to pass its value to a stored procedure

My SQL Code

```
CREATE PROC [ADD_VACATION]  @vacationStart date ,@vacationEnd date ,@vacationMem nvarchar (100) = NULL ,@idVacationKind_L int ,@idMember_L int

AS INSERT INTO [tblVacation]
           ([vacationStart]
           ,[vacationEnd]
           ,[vacationMem]
           ,[idVacationKind_L]
           ,[idMember_L])
     VALUES
           (@vacationStart
           ,@vacationEnd
           ,@vacationMem
           ,@idVacationKind_L
           ,@idMember_L)
```

C# Code :

```
public void ADD_VACATION(string vacationStart,string vacationEnd, string vacationMem, int idVacationKind_L, int idMember_L)
{

    DAL.open();

    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];

    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@vacationStart", SqlDbType.Date);
    param[0].Value = vacationStart;

    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@vacationEnd", SqlDbType.Date);
    param[1].Value = vacationEnd;

    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@vacationMem ", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
    param[2].Value = vacationMem;

    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@idVacationKind_L", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[3].Value = idVacationKind_L;

    param[4] = new SqlParameter("@idMember_L", SqlDbType.Int);
    param[4].Value = idMember_L;

    DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_VACATION", param);
    DAL.close();

}
```

And the event

```
private void btnAddVacation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    cms.ADD_VACATION( dtp_VacationStart.Text, dtp_VacationEnd.Text, txtVacationMemory.Text,
                    Convert.ToInt32(cmbVacationKind.SelectedValue)
                   ,Convert.ToInt32(dgMember_Grade.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));

    MessageBox.Show("Added Successfuly", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

This code gives me an Error : Input string was not in a correct format.

Thanks for you all ... Sorry about confusing .. its my first question

Comment: How are you getting date? From textBox or dateTimePicker? If its dateTimePicker, you have to use `.Value` in place of `.Text`. If its textBox, then you have to use [ParseExact Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The date from dateTimePicker ... i tried to use value but it gives me an error
Argument2: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'String'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SqlParameter` `@vacationStart` is of type `DateTime` but you assign it a string.

You should get the `DateTime` value of the `DateTimePicker` (instead the string representation in `DateTimePicker.Text`):

```
DateTime vacationStart = dtp_VacationStart.Value;
```

and change the signature of `ADD_VACATION`:

```
public void ADD_VACATION(DateTime vacationStart, ...
```

Now you can use it:

```
private void btnAddVacation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime vacationStart = dtp_VacationStart.Value;
    cms.ADD_VACATION(vacationStart, ...
```

Comment: Where i should put 
DateTime vacationStart = dtp_VacationStart.Value; ?

Comment: another error
Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Please use the debugger. Where does the error occur? What is the contents of the respective string?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are entering data in wrong format ...
input data in right format or change the data type

Comment: I Agree With You But The Error is saying Same Thing... So This is not  a Answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert dtp_VationStart.Text and dtp_VacationEnd.Text to Date.

```
cms.ADD_VACATION( Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_VacationStart.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dtp_VacationEnd.Text), txtVacationMemory.Text,
                Convert.ToInt32(cmbVacationKind.SelectedValue)
               ,Convert.ToInt32(dgMember_Grade.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
```

You can also use the DateTime.Parse function. More information can be [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165448.aspx).

Comment: This involves two conversions DateTime->Text->DateTime with all possible format errors. Not what the OP wants...

Comment: error Argument1: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'String'

Answer (score 1):

Arguments of function `ADD_VACATION()` `vacationStart` & `vacationEnd` are of type `string`, while you are passing them in parameters as `SqlDbType.Date`. Change the arguments' type to be `DateTime` and in the calling function `ADD_VACATION()`, use `.Value` for `DateTimePicker` Control. This should solve your problem.